# how i can install and use its (server success but disconnected when i install angularjs schemaform.io)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-schema-form

I use npm test

I RECEIVE MY OUTPUT without erros but this works and close after 20 seconds

but I dont know how use this

```html
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 59 of 90 SUCCESS (0 secs / 4.326 secs)
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 90 of 90 SUCCESS (0 secs / 5.777 secs)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 34 of 90 SUCCESS (0 secs / 4.396 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 90 of 90 SUCCESS (6.43 secs / 5.777 secs)
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 34 of 90 SUCCESS (0 secs / 4.396 secs)
TOTAL: 124 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 124 SUCCESS
[2017-03-01 19:58:05.913] [DEBUG] karma - Run complete, exiting.
```

how I can install and use this angularjs project https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I solve use

./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start --single-run --browsers PhantomJS karma.conf.js

and simple http-server command